# "Racial Flow" in the movie Get Out (2017)

Tags: phrase-meaning

Person 1: I like you on your **racial flow**, though.

Person 2: -Is this a racial flow？

1: - Racial flow.

2: Am I feeling a racial flow？

1: Yeah, youʼre feeling **racially flowy**.

Context is that, Person 1, the guy, is invited over to the house of Person 2, the girl, for the weekend, and is subjected to a lot of racism, and the girl is sorry for her family and she is sorry to have them as her family, since they upset her BF. He says, no need to be sorry, it is nothing important, although he likes her racial flow. My friend suggested that "being on the same flow" might be the meaning I am looking for. On the other hand, I thought he might have found interesting how easily she joins her family in their unintentional racism and she goes with the flow (current). Thanks for your help, sincerely.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more context.  And to know who the speakers were.  Brilliant movie, but I don't remember that particular bit of dialogue.

Comment: Person 1, the guy, is invited over to the house of Person 2, the girl, for the weekend, and is subjected to a lot of racism, and the girl is sorry for her family and she is sorry to have them as her family, since they upset her BF. He says, no need to be sorry, it is nothing important, although he likes her racial flow. My friend suggested that "being on the same flow" might be the meaning I am looking for. On the other hand, I thought he might have found interesting how easily she joins her family in their unintentional racism and she goes with the flow (current).

Thanks again, very much!

Comment: @UtkuOkur edit and add this information into the question please.

Comment: I suspect "racial flow" here might simply be a bad translation, since it has no currency, and I'm not aware of any structurally similar usages. If it *was* current (among some small group of native speakers including your conversant #1) the quirky one-off coinage ***racially flowy*** might have some credibility as a facetious usage, but I think in reality all we have here is a conversation fragment that means little or nothing to me (nor apparently to your conversant #2).

Comment: 'racial flow is not a set phrase (an idiom that means something special, a little more than just the meaning of the parts put together). It probably is referring to the flow, the smooth manner of speaking, about the racial situation in the conversation preceding.

Comment: I agree with Mitch. Flow here is like a synonym for speech. I like your flow [the flow of your speech about race].

Comment: Take a listen to THIS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cjwi4XnRknQ I like your flow. The way you move, the way you are. Etc etc. It doesn't have a set meaning, really.

Comment: @UtkuOkur, see my answer below.  I think your question was a really good one and I think "racial flow" captures in a colloquial way the subtleties and mechanisms of hidden racism in America.  I'd love to ask Jordan Peele about his choice of that phrase.

Comment: @Palizche Is the character black American? Flow is just speech here.

Comment: @Lambie - Are you asking whether the character is African American?  If so, yes, for Person 1, no for Person 2.  The filmmaker is mixed race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Racial flow** may be reference to and synonym for **racial fluidity** that has been made more colloquial. This mixes with
> reference to **sexual flow**.  The movie, Get Out, explores
> black stereotypes held by white people, including the idea that blacks
> possess greater physical and sexual prowess. See this [compilation of clips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVIqOhPqf4w) to get a feel for the movie's point of view about race.

Comments to your question and to an earlier version of my answer make clear that most people think Peele's use of **racial flow** in the scene you describe is simply conversational and not particularly laden with deeper meaning.  I disagree.  I may not have the correct interpretation, but Peele is a serious observer of race in America and I don't think he's using the term **racial flow** without some sort of consciousness about what that means.  The whole movie, in fact, hinges on the **difference between actual racial attitudes and how those attitudes are hidden through misrepresentation and mistaken perceptions.**  Isn't that the **racial flow** of the dialogue you describe?

> In your question. I think the girlfriend **racially flows** with her
> family's  perception of the boyfriend.  She joins them in the racism.
> Presumably, in private she presents herself as more accepting.  She is
> a chameleon in her attitude in that she joins the feel of the
> situation.  The boyfriend admires her ability **to be fluid or to flow
> in her racial attitudes**. It seems to be a double-entendre about **sexual flow** and the allure of racial difference,

A [Zadie Smith essay](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/02/23/brother-another-mother) in *The New Yorker* explores Key and Peele's "chameleon comedy" related to racial identity and states:

> **For Key and Peele “blackness” is a fairly abstract concept. It’s on
> a spectrum and can be turned up or down, as if with a volume knob.**

The Smith essay also speaks of Peele's portrayal of an entitled suburban white girl, not unlike Rose, the character in *Get Out*.

> One of his [Peele's] most successful creations—a nightmarish, overly
> entitled young woman called Meegan—is an especially startling
> transformation: played in his own dark-brown skin, she somehow still
> reads as a white girl from the Jersey Shore.

A blog post about Peele and his comedy partner, Key, is entitled [Keanu, Key and Peele, and the **Fluidity of Race.**](http://thestake.org/2016/04/29/keanu-key-and-peele-and-the-fluidity-of-race/) supports the notion that observers see Peele's interest in **racial fluidity**.  Why shouldn't language in his movie script reflect that cultural idea of fluidity by coining an idiom, **racial flow**?

Racial fluidity is a term that is used by sociologists, journalists and now seems to be appearing in some pop culture contexts.

See [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=racial%20fluidity&utm_source=search-action) entry for **racial fluidity**.

> IT MEANS YOU CAN BE WHATEVER RACE YOU WANT YO. IF YOU FEEL LIKE YOU
> WANNA BE BLACK ONE DAY AND MEXICAN THE NEXT THEN DO IT BRO. DONT LET
> NONE OF THESE HOES TRY TO TELL YOU WHAT RACE YOU IS.
>
> Person 1: hoe you ain't black
>
> Person 2: it's called racial fluidity I can be black if I wanna be
> black, bitch

Again, I may be totally wrong about the precise meaning of **racial flow** intended by the writer-director in the movie's dialogue, but I am quite sure Jordan Peele, a biracial man, is familiar with the term **racial fluidity** and understands that this is part of what he is exploring in his comedy.  The movie plot is not subtle.  It explores the way the minds of black people s are taken over by white people and also, a modern version of slavery.  There's an Asian character in the movie who asks the black character about the advantages and disadvantages of being African American, as though he's deciding which way to aim his **racial flow.**

**Racial flow** also seems to allude to **sexual flow**.  See also [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Flowjob) entry for **flowjob**

> When a girl runs her hands through your **flow**.
>
> Contrary to popular belief, **a flowjob is not the cutting or trimming
> of your flow.**
>
> Chris: "Dude guess what?"  Travis: "What?''  Chris: "I got a
> **flowjob** last night!!"  Travis: "Sweet bro, I'm so jealous. You do have **good flow**."

Comment: Really not. Low-level characters are not expected to be sociologically savvy.

Comment: @Lambie, what do you mean by "low level characters"?   The writer-director, Jordan Peele, seems extraordinarily sociologically savvy.  Highbrow and lowbrow culture routinely mix these days.  See Urban Dictionary entry for "racial fluidity".

Comment: @Paliszhe What I mean is that unless the characters know that sociological term (due to the intellectual level of the character type), the scriptwriter would not put in their speech. But even then, it's a real stretch to imagine the actual characters were intended by the author to know that. You can mix high and low any old way. Nevertheless, there is such a thing as a coherent character. This just sounds like banter to my ear.

Comment: I think you may be on the right track.  (I haven't seen the film because I'm not someone who can handle horror movies.)  I found a script at http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=get-out.  It doesn't label who says what, unfortunately.  What is the action during the various lines of dialogue that you quoted?  From reading that section of the script, I wondered if there was some sexual innuendo in "I like you and your racial flow. Is this a racial flow?" But I wasn't sure. Anyway, back to your answer.  Maria Root's Bill of Rights for People of Mixed Heritage ...

Comment: ... has some parts that fit with your answer, especially for example *I have the right: not to keep the races separate within me, to identify myself differently in different situations, to create a vocabulary, to change my identity over my lifetime--and more than once*. // This transcript looks more accurate: https://vdrive.to/srt/00001/m0wv6al470h6_English.srt

Comment: @Lambie - I don't understand either why you said "low level characters."  Isn't this conversation between the two main characters?  And didn't Peele write the whole script?  I'm confused by your comment.

Comment: @aparente001 My comment is simple. If someone says something, it relates to that character's KNOWN UNIVERSE as imagined by the author. A character would not be made to say something that in some hidden way refers to some conceptual universe unless that is the type of writing it is. This is not that type of writing. And if it were, there would not be such a shift in language. The character is talking to a girl, not invoking sociological arguments.

Comment: @Lambie - We have a young man and a young woman involved in a romantic relationship.  The young man is mixed race and the young woman is white.  Her family is racist.  Are you saying you don't find it believable that the two of them would be aware of racism and attitudes about race in the U.S.?  Are you saying that you don't find it believable that the two of them would talk about that topic?  If that's what you're saying, then perhaps you have a poor opinion of the script.  But I don't see how you get from that to dismissing Palizsche's answer, which points out that the filmmaker...

Comment: ... has done other artistic work around this theme.

Comment: @aparente001, thanks for your perceptions and comments. That's interesting about the possible sexual innuendo.  One of the themes explored by Get Out is the stereotypical notion held by whites that blacks have greater physical and sexual prowess. The horror aspect of the film seems quite horrific to me and I don't have much desire to see it, but it has struck a cultural nerve of some sort.  Peele aims at parody and satire.  The Stepford Wives was an inspiration, but I never saw that, so can't comment.  To clarify though, Peele is biracial, but the main male character is black, not biracial.

Comment: @aparente001, I added the idea of "sexual flow" based on your comment and comments in response to the original question.

Comment: I mistakenly thought Peele was also acting in the picture. // I suspect that if there is a sexual innuendo in the *flow* conversation, it's more abstract than what you quoted from the urban dictionary -- but I'm not sure.

Comment: @aparente001, I understand the Urban Dictionary  is not the ideal source.  It was just a quick way to show that flow is used colloquially in connection with sexuality.  That said, the clips I've seen show the movie is not particularly subtle. Watch a clip compilation if you dare:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVIqOhPqf4w

Comment: Found an interesting use of "racial flow" from 1984: "New Trails in the Old West"  by Louis B. Reynolds.  See page 35 of this pdf: http://documents.adventistarchives.org/Books/TTS1996.pdf